# 1с bitrix Как сохранить авторизацию при многосайтовости на одном домене

Tags: битрикс, авторизация

Подскажите пожалуйста как сохранить авторизацию для группы пользователей при переходе на другой сайт при многосайтовости. В данный момент авторизация сохраняется для админа. В каких файлах смотреть где это настроено для админа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В header.php шаблона установленного на сайт site2.ru условие по которому происходит редирект на  site1.ru
Это означает, что если пользователь администратор или принадлежит группе пользователей с ID равным 13  или 14 авторизация пройдет на сайте site2.ru иначе редирект на site1.ru.

```
if($USER->IsAdmin() or CSite::InGroup( array(13,14)  ) ){
    } else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.site1.ru".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit(); 
}
```